# Why does Rake drop the drive-letter from a rooted path used as a file task name?

Tags: ruby, path, rake

I put my dotfiles in a git repository for safety and mobility. I wrote a simple Rake task to overwrite the dotfiles in my user directory with the ones in the repository, if it's newer. That's a simple `file` task. For example, here's one file task all spelled out so we know nothing goofy is going on...

```rb
file File.expand_path("~/.bashrc") => ".bashrc" do |task|
  system "cp #{task.source} #{task.name}"
end
```

But, when I ask Rake to inspect the task dependencies, I'm missing the drive letter!

```bsh
$ rake -P
rake /Users/anthony/.bashrc
    lib/.bashrc
```

If I setup a "default" task that uses the same path as a dependency instead of a name, I get the drive letter.

```rb
task :default => [File.expand_path("~/.bashrc")]
```

```bsh
$ rake -P
rake default
    C:/Users/anthony/.bashrc
```

---

I'm on Windows 7 Pro x64 using Ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32] in a 32-bit shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer the observed behavior. Take that rakefile

```
file File.expand_path("~/.bashrc") => ".bashrc" do |task|
  system("cp #{task.source} #{task.name}")
end
```

And the output

```
$ rake -P
rake c:/Users/eacwpku/.bashrc
    .bashrc
```

My system hasn't changed that much...

- Windows 7 Pro x64
- ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
- PowerShell 3.0 or mingw (Git Bash)